# Google login button whit firebase in android studio, error: cannot find symbol variable default_web_client_id

Tags: android, firebase, google-authentication

I try to use google sign in button(suggested with firebase) in my android app like this:

```
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END config_signin]

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

But return this error : Error:(112, 51) error: cannot find symbol variable default_web_client_id

If I try to modify my R directory, I can't, so I'm stuck. In the earlier version of my app in the R file, I've `public static final int default_web_client_id=0x7f060079;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`default_web_client_id` is generated by the google-services plugin from the JSON configuration downloaded from Firebase.

Make sure that you've followed the Firebase Android setup described on https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase

1. Add the `google-services.json` from the Firebase console to your app/ module directory
2. Add to `dependencies` in your root build.gradle: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`
3. Apply the plugin at the bottom of your app build.gradle: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: I've deleted and added again the google-services.json and now the error is gone, the google sign in don't work but at least I've no more the error.

Comment: ok, that's a good start! check that the SHA1 of the app has been added in the console that's a common problem with google sign in.